# Make nested components have the same colour

Tags: html, css

I have a nesting of HTML tags:

```
<div className="col-md-4">
  <ul className="list-group">
   //some other tags
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want them all to have the same background colour.

I tried setting the background colour of the topmost one, but the background of the components within it remains white.

The nested tags are distributed through several source files so it would be difficult to change the background colour for each individually.

Therefore, is there an option I can pass to the topmost `div` such that all tags within it have the same background colour?

Comment: I tried but the `list-group` component gets a white background

Comment: You need to show your CSS and/or a demo for us to help. There's nothing to work with here.

Comment: I don't understand what else I need to show you. I just want to put something in the tag `<div className="col-md-4">` such that all nested components have the same background colour.

Comment: The CSS you'll need does not depend on the source location of the HTML. Show us a full HTML snippet (as rendered in the browser) and the CSS you've tried. Without that, any answers are speculative or heavy-handed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply the style to all childrens then you need to use `.my-first-div *` [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) and if you want to apply the style to the elements children, not its grand children then use `.my-second-div > *` [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors). For example like this:

```css
.my-first-div {
    padding: 10px;    
}

.my-first-div * {
    color: red;
}

.my-second-div > * {
    color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="my-first-div">
    <div class="my-second-div">
        <div>First Text</div>
        <div>Second Text</div>
        <div>
            <span>Third Text</span>
        </div>
        <div>Fourth Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JSFIDDLE:** [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kkakajan/zLdkxvtc/1/)